# using jsp request.getContextPath() makes eclipse not recognize css file

Tags: java, html, css, eclipse, jsp

i'm working on a project where i am using a css file.
at first i just liked to it using an absolute url of it's location in the project but the browser didn't see it that way so i added a jsp request.getContextPath() method and that fixed it but now eclipse's preview window doesn't see it. any suggestions?

`<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/cerulean/default.css">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>`

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working, make sure your href path is correct.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>home page!</h2>
    <c:url var="helloWorldUrl"
        value="helloWorld?message=hello world spring sample" />
    <a href="${helloWorldUrl}">Say hello world to spring mvc</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just replaced it with "."
as in

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="./cerulean/default.css">
```